# save XML files in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: windows-explorer, xml, internet-explorer-11

IE11  opens XML files content in a new tab without providing an option of saving files  to disk. How can I force IE11 to save XML files?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue trying to download an XML file instead of opening it in IE. One solution is to use a different browser (such as Chrome), but I didn't feel like installing another browser just to download one file. My workaround was to create a .TXT file containing the text like the following:
[File](http://your.webserver.name/filename.xml)
I then renamed the file to change the file extension to .HTML instead of .TXT, and double-clicked to open it in IE.
In the web page that opens, I could right-click on the File link and select "Save target as...".